# Add argument flags to the build EXEs for single projects only

Tags: texlipse

I'm writing many different documents in TeXlipse, and right now I'm running into the issue that one of them requires `--shell-escape` to be set. Obviously I'd rather not use it for everything, so I'd like to add that flag to the build chain (`pdflatex.exe` to be precise) for that one project only. Is that even possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Hi, could you find anything useful to solve the issue during this time?